# linking library file into DLL then into console application in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll

I want to try linking fftw math library into Dynamic linked library, then use console application to do fftw within DLL that I am making.

However, I have meet the error called : The code execution cannot proceed because libfftw3-3.dll was not found.

I have updated DLL property but still getting error.

1. Properties > Linker> Input > libfftw3-3.lib,
2. Properties > General > Additional Library Directories > 'path of fftw library'

but still failing.

Comment: VSC doesn't have such menus. Do you mean Visual Studio? If yes, you probably need to copy the .dll next to the .exe. Or consider using vcpkg, I believe then it happens automatically.

Comment: DLLs do not expose libraries statically linked with them.

Comment: ***but still failing.*** It should still fail. `libfftw3-3.lib`  is most likely an import library. Which comes with the dll and requires the dll at runtime. The easiest solution is to put `libfftw3-3.dll` in the same folder as your executable.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat . Yes! I mean Visual Studio. I have copied the .dll next to my consoleapplication.exe and it is working! should I keep copy dll next to dll? or can I make something like CMake ?

Comment: I don't know how to do it the right way in VS or CMake. Yes, it should probably happen automatically.

Comment: ***or can I make something like CMake ?*** Yes you can have CMake copy the required dlls into the executable folder using several different methods and some  scripting. Also if you use `vcpkg`  to provide your libraries this is automatic functionality  when you use the `vcpkg`  [toolchain file](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg#vcpkg-with-visual-studio-cmake-projects) with your CMakeLists.txt for your project. Related: [https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/13308](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/13308)